# Overflow detection for the given case

Tags: digital-logic

Two 2's complement numbers having sign bits x and y are added and sign bit of result is z.Then occurence of overflow is indicated by which boolean function?
I believed that overflow occurs when the XOR of the sum and carry is 1 ,there is overflow,else no overflow.Keeping this in mind,I came up with the following truth table:

X                     Y Z Overflow

0 0 0                                   0

0 0 1 1

0 1 0 1

0 1 1 0

1 0 0 1

1 0 1 0

1 1 0 0

1 1 1 1

Is this table correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### When can an overflow happen?

- Adding a positive and a negative number yields a number in between them (lower border inclusive), thus no overflow is possible.
- Adding two positive numbers will always result in a positive number.
- Adding two negative numbers will always result in a negative number.

-> An overflow is only possible when both summands share the same sign.

#### Can an overflow wrap around more than once?

In a n-bit 2's complement number,

- the maximum number is \$2^{n-1}-1\$. Adding two of them yields:
  $$2\cdot(2^{n-1}-1)=2^n-2=-2$$
- the minimum number is \$-2^{n-1}\$. Again adding two of them:
  $$2\cdot(-2^{n-1})=-2^n=0$$

-> In case of an overflow the result will be always negative for positive summands and positive for negative summands.

#### Conclusion

An overflow has happened if, and only if, both summands have the same sign and the result has the other sign.

Comment: So certain cases here will not hold good in the truth  table?

Comment: @user1369975 Yes. Only the cases `001` and `110` are overflows.

Comment: Here z indicates sum or carry?